# Unable to check radio button with float:right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a very odd issue: radio input is not checking on mouse click when parent has float: right. I checked for z-index - there was not any overlaying elements. When I position this div to the same point by margins everything is ok. Has anyone got any suggestions what it could be?

```
<div class="colours pull-right">
    <form>
        <label for="colour-1"><img class="img-circle" src="/Content/img/colours/1.jpg"></label>
        <input id="colour-1" value="1" name="selectedColour" type="radio">
        <label for="colour-2"><img class="img-circle" src="/Content/img/colours/2.jpg"></label>
        <input id="colour-2" value="2" name="selectedColour" type="radio">
        <label for="colour-3"><img class="img-circle" src="/Content/img/colours/3.jpg"></label>
        <input id="colour-3" value="3" name="selectedColour" type="radio">
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you put up the relevant CSS so we can have a look please, and if possible include a snippet

Comment: Please attach your css to the post so that the issue is reproducible

Comment: If thats ok can you do what @Ricky said so we can see your CSS file plz

Comment: @Ricky I only use bootstrap and except it there is no additional css

Comment: @LeraKuznetsova it already has pull-right and radio button checked is working fine I have checked your code.